# Get the parameter count in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

```
class abc
{
  public object test(params object[] par)
  {
    //I need Count of the parameter here which means to check par contains 1 or 1,2
  }

}

I access the class like,

abc obj =new abc();
obj.test(1);
    (or)
obj.test(1,2);
```

my question is, there is possible to send 1 or 1,2 .I need the count of the How many parameters are in the Object in test class?How to do this?

Comment: I can't help wondering why you didn't try accessing the Length of an array?

Answer (score 10):

Use [`Array.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

```
  public object test(params object[] par)
  {
      var count = par == null ? 0 : par.Length;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Length property of object array.

```
public object test(params object[] par)
{         
     int length = par == null ? 0 : par.Length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Length` property
Try This:

```
int len=par.Length;
```